# Cómo Deshacer un realloc exitoso. (Lenguaje C)

Tags: array, c, estructuras-de-datos, manejo-de-memoria

Estoy intentando programar una estructura de datos que tiene dos campos implementados con un array dinámico. Al intentar programar la función que se encargará de aumentar la capacidad de la estructura, me encuentro con el siguiente problema.

Si hago dos `realloc()` secuenciales y compruebo tras el primero que se ha reasignado bien mi array:

- ¿Qué pasa si el segundo `realloc()` me falla?
- ¿Cómo puedo devolver el espacio reasignado a su tamaño original?
- ¿Un `realloc()` con el tamaño anterior sería infalible? ¿O tendría que comprobar también si éste se pudo realizar?

Como estoy solicitando menos memoria, no debería generar ningún problema, ¿o sí? De no ser así, entraría en un problema recurrente. ¿Cómo puedo hacer un programa que gestione bien esta memoria?

Gracias de antemano. Adjunto el código incompleto y la EdD.

```
  struct _Graph {
    Node **nodes; /*!<Dynamic array with the graph nodes */
    List **plconnect; /*!<Adjacency dynamic array list */
    int num_nodes; /*!<Total number of nodes in the graph */
    int num_edges; /*!<Total number of connections in the graph */
    int capacity; /*!<Current size of the dynamically allocated array */
  } ;

  Status graph_increaseCapacity(Graph *g) {
    Node **n = NULL;
    List **l = NULL;
    int i;
    int new_capacity = g->capacity * INCR;
    
    n = realloc(g->nodes, new_capacity * sizeof(Node *));
    if (n == NULL) {
        return ERROR;
    }
    l = realloc(g->plconnect, new_capacity * sizeof(List *));
    if(l == NULL){
        /*Código de error para deshacer el realloc*/
    }
    
    g->capacity = new_capacity;
    g->nodes = n;
    g->plconnect = l;
    
    for (i = (g->num_nodes); i < g->capacity; i++) {
        g->nodes[i] = NULL;
        g->plconnect[i] = NULL;
    }
    return OK;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> #### ¿Qué pasa si el segundo `realloc` me falla?

Pues eso mismo, que ha fallado y no hay memoria suficiente :-)

> #### ¿ Cómo puedo devolver el espacio reasignado a su tamaño original ?
>
> #### ¿ Un realloc con el tamaño anterior sería infalible ?
>
> #### ¿ O tendría que comprobar también si éste se pudo realizar ?

La documentación es bastante laxa:

> The realloc function returns a pointer to the new object (which may have the same value as a pointer to the old object), or a null pointer if the new object could not be allocated.

Pero deja poco lugar a la interpretación: Un `realloc( )` puede *fallar* **en cualquier momento**; cada llamada es independiente de la anterior, y no existe **ninguna garantía**, incluso para el caso de `volver a un tamaño anterior`.

> #### ... Porque de no ser así entraría en un problema recurrente. ¿ Cómo puedo hacer un programa que gestione bien esta memoria ?

Si una reserva de memoria *falla*, pues ha fallado. Tu única opción es *volver sobre tus pasos*, liberando ... hasta que obtengas una *reserva* exitosa.

Otra estrategia es **no usar `realloc( )`**, llamando exclusivamente a `malloc( )` y `free( )`. De este modo, **nunca** se te dará el caso que expones. Simplemente, difieres la copia de los bloques hasta que se hayan satisfecho todos tus llamadas a `malloc( )`. Si alguna de las llamadas retorna `NULL`, pues simplemente llamas a `free( )` y listo, tu programa queda en el estado anterior.

*Intuitivamente* esta solución parece poco eficiente ... hasta que caemos en la cuenta de que **no hay ninguna garantía de que `realloc( )` *reutilice* el puntero**. En otras palabras ... ¿ como sabemos que `realloc( )` no está haciendo ya **justamente eso** ?